# How to make a GUI that changes a look of a NPC after inserting a player id

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been trying to figure this out but nothing i do seems to work. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own accessories, which the data of you can find by using `game.Players.GetCharacterAppearanceInfoAsync(userId)`

See more documentation here: https://developer.roblox.comen-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetCharacterAppearanceInfoAsync